# Is it possible to test new Scratch Org Settings before Winter 19 is released to Production?

Tags: salesforcedx

I wanted to test the new [Scratch Org Settings](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_sfdx_scratch_orgs_settings.htm) from Winter 19.  Ever since Winter 19 was deployed to (some) sandboxes, all of the Scratch Orgs I've created have been Winter 19.  But when I tried to create an org with these settings, I got an error:

```
ERROR:  No such column 'Settings' on sobject of type ScratchOrgInfo.
```

Seems like a standard "object doesn't have that column" error, so I'm guessing that the error is coming from the Dev Hub org - DX can't populate a Dev Hub object's (`ScratchOrgInfo`) field (`Settings`), because it's new in Winter 19.  And Dev Hubs are always production orgs (although I can't find a definitive reference), so we can't test this until Winter 19 is available in Production.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: hi Jason,

Did you find out the answer. I am looking at Winter 19 DevHub now, and the ScratchOrgInfo object still does not have a Settings field.

It looks like the ScratchOrgDefinition json file doesn't quite match the ScratchOrgInfo schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Winter 19 adds Dev Hub to Developer Edition orgs, if you have a pre-release dev org you should be able to test in there. Sign up here:
https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/prerelease-winter19/

You could also sign up as Enterprise but you'll get a trial org.

Nice thing about the Dev Edition pre-release orgs is, you can keep them around and they will pre-upgrade early every release cycle.