# Scratch Org Creation Error with sfdx

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

I am getting below error when trying to create scratch org.

```
No such column 'Settings' on sobject of type ScratchOrgInfo.
```

Here is my org definition json file -

```
{
    "orgName": "offer",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "features": ["Communities"],
    "settings": {
        "orgPreferenceSettings": {
            "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
            "networksEnabled": true,
            "enableLiveAgent": true
        },
        "nameSettings": {
            "enableMiddleName": true,
            "enableNameSuffix": true
        }
    }
}
```

Command I am running -

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a SO6 -v ConsumerProd
```

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: Are you on latest version of CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my cli version and after that it started working.

Answer (score 1):

The structure looks correct to me.

Googling the full message produces a few matches including this [Is it possible to test new Scratch Org Settings before Winter 19 is released to Production?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/235361/is-it-possible-to-test-new-scratch-org-settings-before-winter-19-is-released-to) that relates to before Winter '19 being GA so probably isn't the problem. But it does suggest that the error is coming from your Dev Hub org so log in to that and check that all looks OK. See e.g. [Manage Scratch Orgs from Dev Hub](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_view_lex.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON Structure is not proper, You have to remove the settings key

```
{
    "orgName": "offer",
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "features": ["Communities"],
     "orgPreferenceSettings": {
            "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
            "networksEnabled": true,
            "enableLiveAgent": true,
            "enabled":["enableMiddleName","enableNameSuffix"]
        }
}
```

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm

Comment: `settings` is actually available with [Winter '19](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm)

Comment: My bad didn't realize, looks like I was in a cave or something....